# changes in css or js files don't show in directadmin

Tags: javascript, css, admin, directadmin

I have changed css/js file appended to my index page. 
When I refresh the index page, changes don't show in the browser. And when I inspect the page, I see old version of my css/js file.

Comment: Clear cache, make sure you are in the right page (sometimes if you have project on some production server, you can mix localhost with that).

Answer (score 1):

You need to clear cache memory or refresh using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> for Win and <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> for Mac